# How many cores TensorFlow use by default (not using Coordinator)?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, cpu-cores

I guess that tensorflow use single core by default (when I don't use 'Coordinator'), because tensorflow is python library.

However, when I see Activity Monitor on Mac with running tensorflow code 
 with default setting, the $CPU of python 3.6 is upper than 100% and the number of thread is greater than 10.

Does tensorflow use multi core by default?

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow is a python library, but it's essentially a wrapper over native C++ implementation. Whenever you define an op, like this:

```py
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
  a = tf.Variable(3.0)
  b = tf.constant(4.0)
  c = a * b
```

... `c` is not a multiplication of python variables `a` and `b`, but a [`tf.multiply`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/multiply) op, that has not so trivial [CPU and GPU implementations](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_mul_1.cc).

So it should not confuse you: tensorflow engine is trying to use all available hardware power to perform operations, in particular, as the [FAQ states](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq#running_a_tensorflow_computation), is multi-core:

> The individual ops have parallel implementations, using multiple cores in a CPU, or multiple threads in a GPU.

By the way, it's worth noting that the `"/cpu:0"` device aggregates all CPUs on a multi-CPU system.
There is currently no way to pin nodes on specific CPUs or to use
just a subset of all CPUs.